# Query works on localhost, but not in production server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb, codeigniter-3

My English is not so good, but I'll try to explain the problem.

I have three tables: One called **Accounts**, one called **Accounts_Profiles** and another called **Accounts_Messages**. My goal is to show the last users that the logged in user ($login_user_id) sent a message to.
My tables basically consists of this:

`Accounts`

id, name, email, nivel, verification

`Accounts_Profiles`

id, user_id, status

`Accounts_Messagens`

id, sender (int), receiver (int)

My query is currently like this:
`SELECT DISTINCT Accounts.id, Accounts.email, Accounts.name, Accounts.username, Accounts.avatar, Accounts.nivel, Accounts.verification FROM Accounts JOIN Accounts_Messages ON Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.receiver ORDER BY Accounts_Messages.id DESC;`

In CodeIgniter/PHP, it looks like this:

```
/*
    With the $this->db->distinct() I make sure that the users shown will not be repeated - It works!
*/
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select(
    array(
        "Accounts.id id",
        "Accounts.email email",
        "Accounts.name name",
        "Accounts.username username",
        "Accounts.avatar avatar",
        "Accounts.nivel nivel",
        "Accounts.verification verification",
        "Accounts_Profiles.status online",
        "(SELECT IF(COUNT(ACM.id) > 0, COUNT(ACM.id), null) FROM Accounts_Messages ACM WHERE ACM.receiver = '$login_user_id' AND ACM.sender = 'Accounts.id' AND ACM.is_read = '0') unread"
    )
);

/*
    Here I exclude the $login_user_id from the list, the admin users and also those who have not verified the account - It works!
*/
$this->db->join(
    "Accounts_Profiles",
    "Accounts_Profiles.user_id = Accounts.id", 
    "left"
);
$this->db->where(
    array(
        "Accounts.id !=" => $login_user_id,
        "Accounts.nivel !=" => 'administrator',
        "Accounts.verification !=" => 'false'
    )
);

/*
    Here, I sort messages by last sent. I check who the logged in user sent the last messages to and list those users - This only works on localhost.
*/
$this->db->join(
    "Accounts_Messages", 
    "Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.receiver", 
    "left"
);
$this->db->order_by(
    "Accounts_Messages.id", 'DESC'
);

/*
    Returning the result
*/
return $this->db->limit($filters['limit'])->offset($filters['offset'])->get("Accounts")->result();
```

The problem:
This works on localhost, but it doesn't work in production. On localhost I use MySQL. On the production server I use MariaDB.
In theory it shouldn't make any difference, since the clauses I used are compatible in both cases.

Am I forgetting to do something or some configuration on the production server?

Thank you!

I tried to add this for conscience sake, but it didn't work:
`$this->db->group_by( "Accounts.id" );`

---

### Edit

As you can see, in localhost the ordering of users is given by the last message sent to them. That's what I expect in production.
[image]

On the production server the ordering is happening by conversation creation date (I don't know how). It's wrong, as the first users I chat with always come last even if I send them a new message.
[image]

Comment: "it doesn't work in production" - what does that mean? What happens if you run it? Is there any error thrown? Also, you should use the same database system in your development system to avoid such problems

Comment: Hi, @NicoHaase! I've been running the same tests on the same machines for at least 5 years... This is the first time I've seen this issue. It does not display errors. Sorting simply does not go as it should. The code is exactly the same in both cases (localhost and live server). Everything always worked fine. I've never made something to work exclusively with MariaDB.

Comment: Can you run the query `SELECT VERSION();` on both local and production server, and report what each says?

Comment: Hi, @BillKarwin! Sure! 

MySQL: 8.0.31. 
MariaDB: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly against the database? And it may seem like a silly question, but did you upload the data to the production database?

Comment: Hey, @aynber! Thanks for the question. Yes, the two databases are exactly the same. There are no differences between them. I tried running the query via terminal and also via PhpMyAdmin... it only works on localhost. :/

Comment: And what happens when you run it on the production system? Does it yield an empty result?

Comment: Him @NicoHaase!
Does not return empty results. It returns a list with different ordering than the one I defined in the query. My query should return the last users I sent a message to, in descending order (and this is what happens on localhost). In short, in production it sorts by conversation creation date instead of sorting by message id.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the query is not running properly when you use something like phpMyAdmin, this does not look related to CodeIgniter to me. Share the table structure, sample data, the query, and the expected output

Comment: Thank you, @NicoHaase! I already edited the question with what you mentioned.

Comment: I can't test your query with MySQL 5.7 or 8.0. It returns the error: `"ERROR 3065 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'test.Accounts_Messages.id' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT"`. The same error is returned by MySQL 5.7. So either you are testing a different query than the one you show, or else you aren't really running those versions of MySQL.

Comment: MariaDB does not return that error. This shows a more general point: MariaDB is not compatible with MySQL. MariaDB started in 2010 as a fork of MySQL, but both products have changed enough that we should all stop thinking of them as compatible. You should use the same brand and version in development that you use in production.

Comment: Let's see if I understand what you are trying to do here. You have a user_id ($login_user_id) and you want a list of Accounts info from all the recipients of that userid's mails ordered by most recent first? Right?

Comment: Hi, @BillKarwin! This compatibility issue I solved by doing this: SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')); SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: Thanks to all of you who tried to help me. I solved the problem. I will edit the post explaining what I did to solve it.

Comment: @JesseGaspar please consider to remove the "EDIT 2 - solved" block completely and post it as an self-answer to your question. To explain: Stack Overflow is not a forum, but a Q/A site. It has a Question (Q) section, that's the one were you ask your Q. And it has an answer (A) section were other users (or yourself) can answer your Q. See 
[**Can I answer my own question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I managed to solve the problem by doing the following adjustment in the query:

```
SELECT Accounts.id, Accounts.email, Accounts.name, Accounts.username, Accounts.avatar, Accounts.nivel, Accounts.verification, Accounts_Messages.id
FROM Accounts 
JOIN (
    SELECT m_to, MAX(dt_updated) as max_updated
    FROM Accounts_Messages
    GROUP BY m_to
) last_message
ON Accounts.id = last_message.m_to
JOIN Accounts_Messages 
ON Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.m_to AND Accounts_Messages.dt_updated = last_message.max_updated
GROUP BY Accounts.id, Accounts_Messages.id
ORDER BY last_message.max_updated DESC;
```

It looks like this in CodeIgniter:

```
<?php
    /*
        With the $this->db->distinct() I make sure that the users shown will not be repeated
    */
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select(
        array(
            "Accounts.id id",
            "Accounts.email email",
            "Accounts.name name",
            "Accounts.username username",
            "Accounts.avatar avatar",
            "Accounts.nivel nivel",
            "Accounts.verification verification",
            "Accounts_Messages.id acmid",
            "Accounts_Profiles.status online",
            "(SELECT IF(COUNT(ACM.id) > 0, COUNT(ACM.id), null) FROM Accounts_Messages ACM WHERE ACM.m_to = '$login_user_id' AND ACM.m_from = 'Accounts.id' AND ACM.is_read = '0') unread"
        )
    );

    /*
        Here I exclude the $login_user_id from the list, the admin users and also those who have not verified the account
    */
    $this->db->join(
        "Accounts_Profiles",
        "Accounts_Profiles.user_id = Accounts.id", 
        "left"
    );
    $this->db->where(
        array(
            "Accounts.id !=" => $login_user_id,
            "Accounts.nivel !=" => 'administrator',
            "Accounts.verification !=" => 'false'
        )
    );

    /*
        Here, I sort messages by last sent. I check who the logged in user sent the last messages to and list those users
    */
    $this->db->join(
        "(SELECT m_to, MAX(dt_updated) as max_updated FROM Accounts_Messages GROUP BY m_to) last_message", 
        "Accounts.id = last_message.m_to", 
        'inner'
    );
    $this->db->join(
        "Accounts_Messages", 
        "Accounts.id = Accounts_Messages.m_to AND Accounts_Messages.dt_updated = last_message.max_updated", 
        'inner'
    );
    $this->db->group_by(
        "Accounts.id, Accounts_Messages.id"
    );
    $this->db->order_by(
        "last_message.max_updated", 
        "DESC"
    );
?>
```